# What is the purpose of making getaddrinfo() as a server program?

Tags: sockets

I was watching Computer Network on Coursea. `getaddrinfo` makes sense for the client program (to resolve the server name to a network address), but why does a server program needs `getaddrinfo` to bind to a socket?

Please see page 12 on https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/comnetworks/lect%2F1-4-sockets-ink.pdf

Thanks.

---

Here is tutorial from Python.
http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#creating-a-socket

As you see I can do assign a port at the bind. But there is `getaddrinfo()` in the `_socketobject` level. (try access `serversocket.getaddrinfo()`).

---

**EDIT**

Okay. Based on nos's comment, I think this is what he meant.

Supposed you want to run your own SSH program on port 22. For sake of OS portability, since the port is defined in `/etc/services` you can ask socket to translate the port from OS.

```
import socket
# create an INET, STREAMing socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# bind the socket to a public host, and a well-known port
ssh_addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), 'ssh')[0][4]
serversocket.bind(ssh_addrinfo)
# become a server socket
serversocket.listen(5)
serversocket.close()
```

`ssh_addrinfo` looks like this:

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), 'ssh')
[(2, 2, 17, '', ('192.168.33.1', 22)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('192.168.33.1', 22)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('192.168.1.4', 22)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('192.168.1.4', 22)), (30, 2, 17, '', ('fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe1e:4985%en0', 22, 0, 4)), (30, 1, 6, '', ('fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe1e:4985%en0', 22, 0, 4))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a textual name for the port(service) in e.g. /etc/services, and have the server look that up with getaddrinfo() to learn which port it should listen on.

That step is optional though, you can set the port number by other means.

Comment: I confused `getaddrinfo` with `getsockname`.

Comment: Okay I think i understand now, more or less. Based on the Python tutorial and your comment, it would be ``serversocket.bind(("localhost", socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), 'ssh')))`` which will bind a service on ssh port.